# jquery DataTable cant read JSON data

Tags: jquery, datatables

My JSON includes both string and int values. HTML table columns match with DataTable columns. DataTables data is being loaded through ajax. Everything seems fine but I am getting error

```
DataTables warning: table id=blackListMailTable - Requested unknown parameter 'Id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h3>All Black List Mails</h3>
    <hr />
    <br />
    <table id="blackListMailTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

DataTable code:

```
//making the table
var table;
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#blackListMailTable')) {
    table.ajax.reload();
}
else {
    table = $("#blackListMailTable").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: ".....",
            method: "GET",
            dataSrc: ""
            //success: function (data) {
            //    console.log(data);
            //},
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "Id" },
            { data: "Email" },
            { data: "Module" },
            { data: "Status" }
        ]
    });
}
```

I tested the JSON data by using success option of the ajax call. and in browsers console i got this JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":2,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":3,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":4,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":5,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":6,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   },
   {  
      "Id":7,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Bounced"
   },
   {  
      "Id":10002,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Bounced"
   },
   {  
      "Id":10003,
      "Email":"***",
      "Module":"MailChimp",
      "Status":"Unsubscribed"
   }
]
```

I tried using `mData` but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any column value as blank in jsonResponse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this may be some fields don't have data

```
columns: [
            { data: "Id",defaultContent: '' },
            { data: "Email",defaultContent: '' },
            { data: "Module",defaultContent: '' },
            { data: "Status",defaultContent: '' }
        ];
```

other wise remove

```
dataSrc:""
```

Answer (score 0):

If your jsonResponse contains some null or blank value, then you can add `defaultContent` to your `columns`.  which is similar to mysql default value.

```
 table = $("#blackListMailTable").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: ".....",
            method: "GET",
            dataSrc: ""
            //success: function (data) {
            //    console.log(data);
            //},
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "Id" , defaultContent: "" },
            { data: "Email", defaultContent: "" },
            { data: "Module", defaultContent: "" },
            { data: "Status", defaultContent: "" }
        ]
    });
```

one more issue i can see is :
as you used

```
if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#blackListMailTable')) {
    table.ajax.reload();
}
```

this function checks

> if #blackListMailTable is a DataTable. "If yes, initialise:"

so, it will throw re-initiaze error. to resolve that add `!` not condition in your if.

```
if (!$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#blackListMailTable')) {
   table.ajax.reload();
}
```

it means :

> if #blackListMailTable is a DataTable. "If no, initialise: